# (Pyinstaller, Torch) Exception: Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen

Tags: python-3.x, dll, pyinstaller, torch

I am trying to convert my python file, which is importing torch, into an executable. It works perfectly fine when I run the script as the .py file.

Additional Information:

- Python Version: 3.7
- Torch version: 1.5

  - `pip install torch===1.5.0 torchvision===0.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html)`

Please let me know if you need more information.

**My SPEC file:**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['B:\\boska\\Documents\\Dilan\\Dropbox\\Fiverr\\Jobs\\Work Files\\ank521\\Application.py'],
             pathex=['B:\\Downloads\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\torch\\bin', 'B:\\boska\\Documents\\Dilan\\Dropbox\\Fiverr\\Jobs\\Work Exports'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['tkinter', 'sklearn.utils._cython_blas', 'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs', 'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree', 'sklearn.tree._utils', 'torch', 'numpy'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['PySide2', 'PyQt5'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Application',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Application')
```

**My Error Message:**

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is how I solved it:

First, I checked the dependencies of the file 'caffe2_nvrtc.dll' by running the following command:

```
pyi-bindepend caffe2_nvrtc.dll
```

I noticed that an other dll named 'nvcuda.dll' was missing, i.e. had not been included in the dist directory created by pyinstaller.

Therefore, I modified my spec file to add this dll, located in 'C:\Windows\System32'.
Just add the following lines in the spec file:

```
MISSING_LIBS = (
Path(r'C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll'),
)

a.binaries += TOC([(lib.name, str(lib.resolve()),'BINARY') for lib in MISSING_LIBS])
```

If it is not clear, look at this [example](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/inselect/blob/196a3ae2a0ed4e2c7cb667aaba9a6be1bcd90ca6/inselect.spec#L35) of spec file